# Java toString() override for P

Tags: java, overriding, tostring

I am trying to print these songs from an array list which looks like this:
After adding the songs, I have to remove one of the songs and display the songs left, but I am not sure how I would override the toString() method because my output looks like this

Output:

```
com.tdd.bll.Song@5e6a13
com.tdd.bll.Song@862041
com.tdd.bll.Song@1af9d1c
com.tdd.bll.Song@73a35c
com.tdd.bll.Song@1ea25aa

@Test
public void AddSongTest() {
    moesList.addSong(new Song("Alone", "Tech N9ne"));
    moesList.addSong(new Song("Wings", "Macklemore"));
    moesList.addSong(new Song("One More Night", "Maroon 5"));
    moesList.addSong(new Song("Words I Never Said", "Lupe Fiasco"));
    moesList.addSong(new Song("Dumb It Down", "Lupe Fiasco"));
    moesList.addSong(new Song("Nobody's Perfect", "J.Cole"));
    assertEquals(6, moesList.songCount());
}



@Test
public void RemoveSongTest() {     
  AddSongTest();
  moesList.removeSong(1);
  assertEquals(5, moesList.songCount());
  moesList.SongsLeft();
}
}

public void removeSong(int songsNumber) {
  songs.remove(songsNumber);
}

public void SongsLeft(){
  //System.out.print(songs.iterator().next());
  Iterator<Song> iterator = songs.iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in the class Song add a method which has the name toString() which returns the name of the song.

```
public String toString(){ 
    return theMemberVariableWithSongNameInIt ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am not sure how I would override the toString() method in order to get the information from the songs.

Comment: public String toString(){ return theMemberVariableWithSongNameInIt ;}

Comment: Thank you! I'm really starting to get the hang of the way classes and objects work.